# How can I configure Forward proxy from apache on linux

Tags: apache, proxy, forward-proxy

I'm trying to configuring forward proxy my Apache Server on linux.
Apache Server ver.2.4.8

I'm tried coneect to 'http://example.com'. but, Response Code is 500.
I think Path and Query string not be contained on my proxy request.
What is Problem?

My configuration is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log"

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost Off

    <Location /outbound/server>
        ProxyPass <http://example.com>/outbound/server
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/outbound/server
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```